# What's $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(\alpha+x) - \cos \alpha}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to calculate the above limit. Using sage math, I already know that the solution is going to be $-\sin(\alpha)$, however, I fail to see how to get to this conclusion.

### My ideas

I've tried transforming the term in such a way that the limit is easier to find:
\begin{align}
    \frac{\cos(\alpha + x) - \cos(\alpha)}{x} 
    &= \frac{\cos(x)\cos(\alpha)-\sin(x)\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)}{x} & (1) \\
    &= \frac{\cos(x)\cos(\alpha)-\cos(x)}{x} - \frac{\sin(x)\sin(\alpha)}{x} & (2) \\
    &= \frac{\cos(\alpha)(\cos(x)-1)}{x} - \sin(\alpha) & (3) \\
\end{align}

However, I'm not sure whether term $(3)$ is enough to solve the problem. Surely, for $x \to 0$, this evaluates to $\frac{0}{0} - \sin(\alpha)$, which is not enough to determine the limit.

Another try was to transform the term in such a way that I can use $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. For instance, I found that
$$
\frac{\cos(\alpha + x) - \cos(\alpha)}{x}  = \frac{\sin(\alpha - 90^° + x) - \sin(\alpha-90^°)}{x} \qquad (4)
$$

However, this only seems to lead to more complicated term manipulations that I did not manage to bring to a useful point.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This is the definition of the derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation of the derivative of $\cos(x)$ from geometry goes the way you went, but now you need to provide some justification for the equality $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0$, which can also be done using geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make things more complicated than they are. This quotient is the rate of variation of the function of $x$: $\cos(\alpha +x)$, hence its limit is the derivative of the function at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and from here

$$ x\frac{\cos(\alpha)(\cos(x)-1)}{x^2} - \sin(\alpha) \to0\cdot \left(-\frac{\cos \alpha}2\right) -\sin(\alpha)=-\sin \alpha$$

indeed recall

$$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2} \to -\frac12$$

As an alternative refer to derivative definition if you are allowed tu use that.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\cos(\alpha + x) - \cos(\alpha)=-2\sin(\alpha+\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2})$ to get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -\sin(\alpha+\frac{x}{2})\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}$$